# Writing function in r (for loops), keeps replacing previously stored output

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm having difficulty writing a function. I have what I need it to do, but for every loop, I need the answers to fill up the object by row. But it keeps replacing the last answers instead and only gives me the last set. I've read up on a few things but I can't make sense of it with my function as I'm fairly new to all this. If anyone has any advice, that would be much appreciated.

```
for(i in 1:N){
  x <- matrix(as.numeric(fun[i,1:9]), ncol=1)
  res = cbind(
    log(fit$prior[1]) - 
      (0.5*t(fit$means[1,])%*%solve(cov)%*%fit$means[1,]) + 
      (t(x)%*%solve(cov)%*%fit$means[1,]),
    log(fit$prior[2]) - (0.5*t(fit$means[2,])%*%solve(cov)%*%fit$means[2,]) + 
      (t(x)%*%solve(cov)%*%fit$means[2,]),
    log(fit$prior[3]) - (0.5*t(fit$means[3,])%*%solve(cov)%*%fit$means[3,]) + 
      (t(x)%*%solve(cov)%*%fit$means[3,]),
    log(fit$prior[4]) - (0.5*t(fit$means[4,])%*%solve(cov)%*%fit$means[4,]) + 
      (t(x)%*%solve(cov)%*%fit$means[4,]),
    log(fit$prior[5]) - (0.5*t(fit$means[5,])%*%solve(cov)%*%fit$means[5,]) + 
      (t(x)%*%solve(cov)%*%fit$means[5,]),
    log(fit$prior[6]) - (0.5*t(fit$means[6,])%*%solve(cov)%*%fit$means[6,]) + 
      (t(x)%*%solve(cov)%*%fit$means[6,]))
}
res
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the different values taken `res` in your loop. In order to do, you can for instance declare `res` as a list and assign the result for every value of `i` in `res[[i]]`, like so:

```
res <- list()
for(i in 1:N){
  x <- matrix(as.numeric(fun[i,1:9]), ncol=1)
  res[[i]] <- cbind(
    log(fit$prior[1]) - 
      (0.5*t(fit$means[1,])%*%solve(cov)%*%fit$means[1,]) + 
      (t(x)%*%solve(cov)%*%fit$means[1,]),
    log(fit$prior[2]) - (0.5*t(fit$means[2,])%*%solve(cov)%*%fit$means[2,]) + 
      (t(x)%*%solve(cov)%*%fit$means[2,]),
    log(fit$prior[3]) - (0.5*t(fit$means[3,])%*%solve(cov)%*%fit$means[3,]) + 
      (t(x)%*%solve(cov)%*%fit$means[3,]),
    log(fit$prior[4]) - (0.5*t(fit$means[4,])%*%solve(cov)%*%fit$means[4,]) + 
      (t(x)%*%solve(cov)%*%fit$means[4,]),
    log(fit$prior[5]) - (0.5*t(fit$means[5,])%*%solve(cov)%*%fit$means[5,]) + 
      (t(x)%*%solve(cov)%*%fit$means[5,]),
    log(fit$prior[6]) - (0.5*t(fit$means[6,])%*%solve(cov)%*%fit$means[6,]) + 
      (t(x)%*%solve(cov)%*%fit$means[6,]))
}
res
```